# Monitor spawned processes (process tree) from AHK

Tags: process, tree, autohotkey, pid

I've been serching (search engine, SO, AHK forums) without success how to get the PIDs of the hierarchy tree of anything ran by `Run[Wait]` command.

Any help/directiono will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can query process details via win api [Win32_Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process), AHK example [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ComObjGet.htm#Examples). You can build the process tree of any root process by recursively reading `ParentProcessId`.

Comment: Thanks, I did and its so slow I can't believe it. I'll wait for another answer meanwhile I have a working DLL call that does it far better. Will post as an answer if nothig comes.

Comment: Right off the bat: You may be calling `Select * ...` multiple times which might be the reason for bad performance. Try instead selecting all processes at once and processing the data in-memory. Then again, why don't you post your code here so that we can improve it together?

Comment: No, I was selecting just ProcessId,ParentProcessId WHERE ParentProcessId = pid. OTOH, selecting all PIDs and iterating for earch child was better. Silly me, such an oversight. Thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 20 iterations looking for a 30-child process tree my average times were:

- DLL: 0.2587435
- WMI: 0.1113015

Here's the bench:

```
pid := 7880
loops := 20

time_dll := 0
Loop, % loops
{
    QPC(1)
    tree_dll := processTree(pid)
    time_dll += QPC()
}
time_dll /= loops

time_wmi := 0
Loop, % loops
{
    QPC(1)
    tree_wmi := processTree(pid, True)
    time_wmi += QPC()
}
time_wmi /= loops

MsgBox,,>, % "DLL: " time_dll "`nWMI: " time_wmi

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

processTree(pid, wmi := False, obj := False)
{
    Local
    tree := []
    If wmi
    {
        If !obj
            obj := ComObjGet("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("SELECT ProcessId,ParentProcessId FROM Win32_Process")
        tree := []
        For result in obj
            If pid = result.ParentProcessId
            {
                tree.Push(result.ProcessId)
                subs := %A_ThisFunc%(result.ProcessId, True, obj)
                For idx,val in subs
                    tree.Push(val)
            }
    }
    Else
    {
        Static MAX_PATH := 260 << !!A_IsUnicode
        Static varCapacity := MAX_PATH
        VarSetCapacity(lppe, varCapacity)
        NumPut(varCapacity, lppe, "UInt")
        hSnapshot := DllCall("CreateToolhelp32Snapshot", "UInt",0x2, "UInt",pid, "Ptr")
        DllCall("Process32First", "Ptr",hSnapshot, "Ptr",&lppe)
        Loop
        {
            parent := NumGet(lppe, 16 + A_PtrSize * 2, "UInt")
            If (parent = pid)
            {
                child := NumGet(lppe, 8, "UInt")
                tree.Push(child)
                gchilds := %A_ThisFunc%(child)
                For idx,val in gchilds
                    tree.Push(val)
            }
        } Until !DllCall("Process32Next", "Ptr",hSnapshot, "Ptr",&lppe)
        DllCall("CloseHandle", "Ptr",hSnapshot)
    }
    Return, tree
}

QPC(start := 0)
{
    Static P := 0, F := 0, Q := DllCall("QueryPerformanceFrequency", "Int64P",F)
    Return !DllCall("QueryPerformanceCounter", "Int64P",Q) + (start ? (P:=Q)/F : (Q-P)/F)
}
```

Comment: Nice one. You might get a boost from sorting by parent PID and maybe doing binary search. This should reduce the number of lookups drastically. Or equally promising and easier to implement: Build your own object/dictionary and group all processes by parent PID.

Comment: I like the idea, but that will be just overkill... this will be part of a user interaction, so a tenth of a second seems a fair trade. Thanks a lot for the help and insights.